# Google play review old version code under stopped track?

Tags: android, google-play

I upload a new **version code 59** to Play Store in
both Production/Open testing/closed testing/internal testing.

Then I got rejected mail about **version code 55**. It is in the stopped track of closed testing. And this issue is already fixed in version code 59.

[image]

[image]

I try to send an appeal to Play Store by writing about version code 55 is in stopped track. But it is not working and still got rejected mail because of version code 55.

Currently I upload new version code in the stopped track also and send review again. I need to wait up to 7 days.

Please give me some suggestions if you have the same problem.
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to also upload the new, compliant version to all the other tracks (including stopped ones) that contain APK 55 as this is how Google usually requires it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play reviews all tracks (including stopped tracks).

If you have a new version, you need to make sure two things

1. upload a new version in **all tracks** (Internal / Closed / Open testing / Production) including the **stopped tracks**.
2. go to **App bundle explorer** and check only the new version is in Active state. If other bundles/APKs are Active, Google will review this version also.